# Linux search for a string in a line but replace another string in that line

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

If test.txt file is

```
GREEN Volks RUNNING
GREEN Audi STOPPED
GREEN Merc RUNNING
```

I can grep STOPPED and replace it with sed as following

```
grep "STOPPED" test.txt |sed 's/^GREEN/RED/g'
```

Which returns following output

```
RED Audi STOPPED
```

But instead I would like try something like

```
 sed -i 's/^GREEN/RED/g'| grep "STOPPED" test.txt
```

to see the output as following:

```
GREEN Volks RUNNING
RED Audi STOPPED
GREEN Merc RUNNING
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot have the output you mention (with `GREEN Merc RUNNING`) if you do a `grep "STOPPED" test.txt ` before (the output line above would not match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
  sed '/STOPPED/s/^GREEN/RED/'
```